# No idea how I got this bug ~> C

Tags: c, debugging

So, I have some code that reads a file line by line.
Here is that code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct alumnus {

    int *yearGraduated;
    char firstName[30];
    char lastName[30];

} Alumns;

void printer ( Alumns *a ) {

    printf("Year: %*d", a->yearGraduated);
    printf("  First Name: %s", a->firstName);
    printf("  Last Name: %s", a->lastName);

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Alumns a;
    char *home = getenv("HOME");
    char path[100] = "/Desktop/Alumni.txt";
    strcat(home, path);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(home, "r");

    while ( fp ) {

     fscanf(fp, "%d,%s,%s", a.yearGraduated, a.firstName, a.lastName);
     printer(&a);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

I am getting an error @ line 2 in the printer function

```
printf("Year: %d", a->yearGraduated);
```

My IDE says the following about this line:
    Format Specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'

Another error only appears when I compile the code. Error is at line:

```
a.yearGraduated, a.firstName, a.lastName);
```

My IDE says this about it:
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

Yes, the file IS existent, and yes, it is formatted the right way.
Any ideas on how to debug this?
I was recommended to make the int inside the structure not a pointer, but I'm not sure.

Comment: "*Format Specifies type 'int' but the argument has type 'int *'*" + "*No idea how I got this bug*" - really?

Comment: I've tried changing several things around, and I still get this bug, just in different places. So yes, really.

Answer (score 2):

yearGraduated is a pointer.  You need to allocate space for it and dereference it in the printf statement.

So...

```
 a.yearGraduated = malloc(sizeof(int));

 fscanf(fp, "%d,%s,%s", a.yearGraduated, a.firstName, a.lastName);

 free(a.yearGraduated);
```

and in the function

```
 printf("Year: %d", *a->yearGraduated);
```

or you could make the int in the structure not a pointer and it will not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the first error: all the information you need is in the error message. You provide a pointer to an `int` where `printf` expects an `int`. Unless you have a reason to make `yearGraduated` a pointer you should change it to an `int`:

```
typedef struct alumnus{
    int yearGraduated;
    ...
} Alumns;
```

If you do this you need to change the first argument to `fscanf` to pass the address of `a.yearGraduated`: `&a.yearGraduated`.

If you choose to keep it a pointer you must allocate it:

```
Alumns a;
a.yearGraduated = malloc(sizeof a.yearGraduated);
```

Then in the printer you must dereference it to `printf`:

```
printf("Year: %*d", *a->yearGraduated);
```

The reason the code crashes at the `fscanf` is because the memory at `a.yearGraduated` was not allocated so `fscanf` tries to write to unallocated memory, which is a bad idea.

**ADD**: (in response to your comment)

The reason the program loops forever is because `while(fp)` will loop forever (unless `fopen` fails, in which case it won't loop at all). I'm assuming your reasoning is that `fp` will become false when the end of the stream is reached. But `fp` is just a (pointer-)value and `fscanf` won't (can't) change it. To stop the loop when the end of the stream is reached use [`feof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/feof)

Comment: Okay, since this involves reading a file, I might as well ask. This code is getting the same value every time, and printing it out forever. Even if I add a newline statement to the fscanf part of the code. Any ideas?